# How to build MongoDB documentation locally?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB documentation github project :
https://github.com/mongodb/docs

Build is supposed to be just, but doesn't work

- `python2 -m pip install giza`
- `make html`

I have `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`
python2 is `Python 2.7.18` 
python3 is `Python 3.8.10`

Comment: Python 2 is end-of-life. Maybe, ironically, the documentation is out of date. Using Python 3.10.2, I can install giza just fine.

Comment: i can't update the documentation, so i try to find a way to build it, if you manage to build that documentation somehow it will help alot.

Comment: I was trying to suggest that you try again with `python3` instead of `python2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it using this

```
python2 -m pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-tools/master/giza/requirements.txt
```

also in Makefile remove the examples, because some links are broken i think or the variable doesnt work, and after that , do
`make html`

I found information from this page that gives instructions for MacOs

https://docs.mongodb.com/meta/tutorials/install/

The requirements.txt are (in case link doesn't work in the future)

```
alabaster==0.7.12
argh==0.26.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
Babel==2.7.0
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cryptography==2.7
defusedxml==0.6.0
docutils==0.14
enum34==1.1.6
fett==0.3.2
giza==0.5.18
hieroglyph==1.0.0
idna==2.8
imagesize==1.1.0
ipaddress==1.0.22
Jinja2==2.10.1
jira==2.0.0
jsx-lexer==0.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
oauthlib==3.0.1
onetimepass==1.0.1
packaging==19.0
pbr==5.3.1
polib==1.1.0
pycparser==2.19
Pygments==2.4.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyparsing==2.4.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rstcloth==0.2.6
six==1.12.0
snowballstemmer==1.9.0
Sphinx==1.6.6
sphinx-intl==1.0.0
sphinxcontrib-httpdomain==1.7.0
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.2
typing==3.7.4
urllib3==1.25.3
Wand==0.5.4
```